# Heroku H14 error for a worker?

Tags: heroku

I'm getting a lot of H14 errors. I read about it and it's due to web process not running, but I deployed a worker so it should indeed not be running. Why am I getting these errors then? Precisely, my Procfile is definad as: worker: python bot.py
Here's the log from papertrail:
[image]

Also, a little bit unrelated question, do Heroku workers fall asleep too or is it only for web apps?

Answer (score 0):

The H14 errors are coming from the Heroku Router because something is making a Web request to `/`. The worker process seems to be running fine, at least there are no errors in the log. So I think you've got everything set up right for a worker only app but if you (or anybody else) sends your applicaion a Web request the router will continue to log errors.

According to the docs worker only apps don't sleep but you may run out of free dyno hours if you leave it running indefinitely (and are not on a paid dyno plan). See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping